# Grade complaints: Master's thesis

Tags: thesis, masters

I received my master's thesis grade today, with comments "weak and insufficient analysis". My supervisor read it and checked it on multiple occasions (before submission) and said it is excellent, even though the topic is complex.  He suggested to focuse on graphs, figures etc (visual presentation). I was also requesting additional resources to provide more thorough analysis, the request was declined due to:  "it is only a master's thesis, so what I am doing is more than enough". I also know he is the only one on faculty to specialise on this topic, so that is definately his comments. Whom and how do I  address these issues?

Answer (score 4):

Presumably, your master's thesis was graded by academics other than your supervisor. Since your supervisor *read it and checked it on multiple occasions* and considered it *excellent*. In particular, your supervisor advised that your analysis is *more than enough* (as opposed to *weak and insufficient*, as remarked by your graders). (I don't understand what is meant by: *that is definately his comments* [since] *he is the only one on faculty to specialise on this topic*. Firstly, what comments? Secondly, non-specialists can evaluate your work.)

> Whom and how do I address these issues?

It seems your supervisor is on your side. I suggest meeting with them and discussing your grade. Assuming your supervisor believes your grade is unfair, they may be willing to champion any appeal and guide you through the process.

Beyond your supervisor, you need to follow whatever appeals procedure your institute has in place. I strongly suggest seeking the advice and support of a friendly faculty member, preferably someone you know reasonably well and someone who either knows the procedure well or is well-connected enough to find someone who is.

Comment: @perenniallydisappointed _Why would you presume this?_ For the reasons I give in sentences two and three, plus the OP seems to believe that they have their supervisor's support. That said, I cannot be sure, which is why my second paragraph - which follows the quote - suggests the OP should tease out a confirmation of the supervisor's belief.

Comment: @perenniallydisappointed Also, I _presume this_ to make my assumptions clear. My answer would be different if the supervisor doesn't believe the grade is unfair.

Comment: @perenniallydisappointed, my first thought, also, was that the grading was by another person/group. Yes, misinterpretation is a possibility, but so is dishonesty by the advisor. But I think the "solution" of working through the advisor is the first step to any solution as the writer here suggests.

Comment: @buffy Assuming _grading was by another person/group_, gives the best starting point, IMO

Comment: *Asking for clarification* is an even better starting point than answering questions on the basis of a tenuous assumption.

Comment: @perenniallydisappointed I respectfully disagree: That places too much of a burden on users that provide answers, especially since many users ask questions and do not promptly respond to comments (and seemingly don't edit questions that often to add clarity). Also, I consider my assumptions to be reasonable, rather than tenuous.

Comment: Tenuous and reasonable are not opposites. It is also reasonable to assume that the master thesis was graded by none other than the supervisor. That's what makes your assumption tenuous.

Comment: @perenniallydisappointed Actually, that'd be an unreasonable assumption under the systems that I'm aware of. Is this common at an institute you're aware of? To me, it seems dangerous for a party invested in a thesis to mark it.

Comment: @user2768 *Is this common at an institute you're aware of?* Yes, many institutes. Not every geographic area on earth has the same academic mores and procedures.

Comment: @perenniallydisappointed I give up: Communicating with you isn't constructive and you selectively delete comments when they don't suit your narrative.

Comment: That's rich! I invited you to explain further why you assumed something, pointing out a different possibility that you had maybe not considered. You doubled down in response, so I replaced the invitation to dialogue with my opinion. (And I don't know what happened to my other comments - likely deleted by moderators.)

Comment: Had you responded in a more constructive manner, we would have found out the real reason much sooner: you don't know any academic institutions where master thesis supervisors grade the thesis (which, you could have recognised, does not mean that such institutions don't exist). Suppose you'd said that, instead of "For the reasons I give in sentences two and three ... which is why my second paragraph ...". I might even had +1'd your answer instead of -1'd it (which is why I commented in the first place).